# Flex mxmlc error loading JVM windows 7 64 bit

Tags: java, apache-flex, sdk

I'am executing this command in my windows 7 console:

```
mxmlc
```

then I get:

```
Error loading: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\client\jvm.dll
```

How to fix this?

the jvm.dll exists in that directory, but why the error occurs?, I've tried to reinstall java, but it didn't helped

Comment: Do you have `%JAVA_HOME%` set?  Also, what does `java -version` output?

Answer (score 3):

The flash compiler, mxmlc, does not run under a 64 bit jvm. According to the 4.6 SDK docs:

*Note: You must use a 32-bit version of the JDK, version 1.5 or later. The command line compilers do not work with a 64-bit JDK.*

Unfortunately, You will need to install a 32 bit jvm.

Comment: If you already have both 64 and 32 bit java installed, make sure to add a line like this one in your batch before the line in which you run mxmlc :    set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6"
mxmlc styles.css